# socket.send outside of io.sockets.on( )

Tags: javascript, sockets, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a loop that querys a database continuously. When the query returns a result, the node.js app will send a message to every client connected to the node server via socket.io v0.8.

**Problem:** `io.sockets.broadcast.send('msg')` is called in the middle of a `setInterval()` loop so it is not within an `io.sockets.on()`'s callback function and thus this will not work. When `io.sockets.send('msg')` is used, no message seems to be sent to the client.

**Node.js code**

```
setInterval(function() {
    util.log('Checking for new jobs...');
    dbCheckQueue(function(results) {
        if (results.length) {
            io.sockets.broadcast.send('hello');
        }
    });
}, 10*1000);
```

However, if the `setInterval` is to be called from within `io.sockets.on('connection',..)`, every connected client will create an additional loop!

**Node.js code**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    setInterval(function() {
        util.log('Checking for new jobs...');
        dbCheckQueue(function(results) {
            if (results.length) {
                io.sockets.send('hello');
            }
        });
    }, 10*1000);
});
```

**Clientside JS**

```
        socket.on('hello', function() {
            console.log('HELLO received');
        })
```

*How can I get a SINGLE loop to run, but still be able to send a message to all connected clients?

Comment: `io.sockets` can be accessed outside of `io.sockets.on`.

Comment: @Eliasdx When I use `io.sockets.broadcast.send('hello')` outside, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined`

Comment: you can only use `broadcast` on a `socket`, e.g. `socket.broadcast.send` within a `io.sockets.on`-callback. however i think you can send to all clients with `io.sockets.send` (with `io.` and without `broadcast`).

Comment: It appears that none of the clients can receive it if I use `io.sockets.send('hello')`

Comment: Hum. if you want to use `socket.on('hello',...)` you must use `socket.emit` instead of `socket.send`.

Comment: If I want to send a message to all clients outside of the `io.sockets.on` callback function, is `io.sockets.send()` the only function I can use? If so, what should I use on the client side instead of `socket.on('hello', ...)`

Comment: Just use `io.sockets.emit('hello')` to send the msg. http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Could you tell me how & where to put the `io.sockets.emit('some_link')` in my question - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435498/how-to-use-socket-ioemit-function-outside-of-socket-function-nodejs-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435498/how-to-use-socket-ioemit-function-outside-of-socket-function-nodejs-express) ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think that this will successfully solve your problem

```
io.sockets.emit('hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving previous answer from [@Nyxynyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741099/nyxynyx)

```
io.sockets.emit('hello')
```

It is equivalent to:

```
io.of('/').emit('hello');
```

If you need a different route, change the `of` function parameter.

Documentation:
https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#server-sockets

Comment: For anyone in the future: `io.of('/').emit('hello');` is actually the better function to use if you're using the redis adapter and rooms: `io.of('/').adapter.remoteJoin(user.socket_id, data.conversation.id);`. The reason being is that `io.sockets` will emit for every person that joins a room.